# VBA Clustered Column Chart Options

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro that scrapes returns from the S&P500 and want to plot them with a Clustered Column chart. However, `ChartType = xlColumnClustered` isn't the chart style I want. I can't seem to find documentation on how to switch between styles of chart types.

```
Sub CreateChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A3:B" & lastRow)
    Dim chartSheet As Worksheet
    Set chartSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ws)
    
    ' Define the chart object
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Set myChart = chartSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=375, Top:=10, Height:=225)
    myChart.chart.SetSourceData Source:=dataRange
    myChart.chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    myChart.chart.HasTitle = True
    myChart.chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Yearly Returns"
    myChart.chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    myChart.chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Year"
    myChart.chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    myChart.chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Returns"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro of the creation of the type of chart you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless which one of those clustered columns you selected, they are all the same chart type: `xlColumnClustered`.  The difference is their formatting, and how the data is displayed.

I recorded two macros, where the only difference was the selection of a different option on that screen you've shared an image of, and both macros use this line to create the chart:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

The formatting is up to you once the chart type has been selected.